# When I use ckeditor toolbar, it adds html tags instead of adding desired effects while displaying

Tags: javascript, grails, ckeditor, grails-2.0, grails-2.2

I am using ckeditor which was working fine when I used it with grails 1.3.7.
Now I upadated my codebase to grails 2.2.4 & ckeditor is giving me some issue.

When I write someting & use toolbar to format it, I get output containing html tags.
For e.g.

I select bold & write something 'This is a text'
it produces output

```
<b> This is a text </b>
```

Is there anything I should add in config to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<ckeditor:editor name="${name}" height="100px" width="98%" toolbar="Mytoolbar">

    ${myText?.decodeHTML()}

</ckeditor:editor>
```

It will give output whatever you want.

Enjoy.

Comment: but I did not use decodeHTML in grails 1.3.7. What has changed in grails 2.2.4 for ckeditor?

Comment: I did not work on `grails 1.3.7` , so I did not have idea that what was the problem. Please read documentation for this.

Comment: This is my data.bodyText

<p><br/>Hi<br/> Long Text... &amp;nbsp;&lt;em&gt

& i m trying to use .html which was working fine before but now does not seem to work.
$("#messageText").html(data.bodyText);

I tried to use your solution here 
data.bodyText.decodeHTML()
but it's giving js error

Comment: I posted my answer which worked for me. Can you please check & let me know if that's the right way?... thanks

Comment: Why are you goin to much inside. Just go to action and save your and repopulate it in ckeditor. see the result. Do not remove any html tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is my text (data.bodyText)

```
<p><br/>Hi<br/> Long Text... &amp;nbsp;&lt;em&gt
```

To remove all html tags I used

```
$('<div/>').html(data.bodyText).text()
```